# ADO.NET SqlCommand and transaction does not update actual db table

Tags: ado.net

I've been trying to update and insert data into an existing database table. I am getting no errors, but the actual table data is not being updated.

This is my code for updating one of the rows:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
            con.Open();

            SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction(); 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = t;
            cmd.CommandText = "Update tblName set PersonName = 'Wes' where PersonID = 2";
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            t.Commit();

            Console.WriteLine("change: "+i);
         }
```

The output is

```
change: 1.
```

The change is happening when it runs but the actual table data is still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show us the **connection string** you're using?

Comment: sure. @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Testing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Comment: The code looks okay to me. How are your checking the result?

Comment: in VS, showing the table data in server explorer. Data is unchanged even after refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from `App_Data` into the output directory `.\bin\debug`) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine against the `.mdf` in `.\bin\debug` - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** (in `App_Data`) in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Testing`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Testing;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: I just want to see if I'm with you, when creating the db in ssms it will not be .mdf file but a dbo. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1926870: no - it's a `.mdf` just the same - but **it's under SQL Server's control** and not being attached and copied around as in your case now